# Program crash while using ObjectMapper with Realm in Swift

Tags: swift, realm, objectmapper

If I use ObjectMapper with normal swift class, I am able to get JSON object created but when I use it with Realm class model, program crash. I tried to play around it ( check whether object exist, then using overriding primaryKey method but didn't help). I used class ListTransform from StackOverFlow and it seems to working fine. Xcode doesn't give any particular information on abend so that I can debug more. Other stackoverflow post doesn't help.

```
            class UserResponse: Object, Mappable {

                // MARK: Properties
                //
                var item = List<Item>()
                dynamic var itemPurchaseDate = NSDate()

                required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
                    self.init()
                }

                func mapping(map: Map) {
                    item    <- (map["item"], ListTransform<Item>())
                    itemPurchaseDate <- (map["itemPurchaseDate"], ISO8601DateTransform())
                }
            }

            class ListTransform<T:RealmSwift.Object where T:Mappable> : TransformType {
                typealias Object = List<T>
                typealias JSON = [AnyObject]

                let mapper = Mapper<T>()

                func transformFromJSON(value: AnyObject?) -> Object? {
                    let results = List<T>()
                    if let value = value as? [AnyObject] {
                        for json in value {
                            if let obj = mapper.map(json) {
                                results.append(obj)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return results
                }

                func transformToJSON(value: Object?) -> JSON? {
                    var results = [AnyObject]()
                    if let value = value {
                        for obj in value {
                            let json = mapper.toJSON(obj)
                            results.append(json)
                        }
                    }
                    return results
                }
            }

            class Item: Object, Mappable {

                // MARK: Properties
                //
                dynamic var itemName = ""

                required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
                    self.init()
                }

                // Mapping between ObjectMapper (JSON) and the model properties
                //
                func mapping(map: Map) {
                    itemName <- map["itemName"]
                }
            }

        class RealmManager {

            // returns a dictionary which represents give mappable object
            //
            func jsonFormat<N: Mappable>(object: N) -> [String: AnyObject] {
                return Mapper().toJSON(object)
            }

           func uploadDataToBackend(someObject: UserResponse) {
                let postData = jsonFormat(someObject)
                print(postData)
        } 
   }

    -----------------------------------------

    Program crash on following lines:
    1. In Item class, program crash on line         itemName <- map["itemName"]
    2. If I comment above line , then I get crash on itemPurchaseDate <- (map["itemPurchaseDate "], ISO8601DateTransform())
```

Also note that, when Item does't have anything, first lines execute but when it does have data, it just crash.
    If you need any more information, please let me know

Answer (score 3):

When serializing Realm model to JSON with ObjectMapper, you need to do within a write transaction. Or detach the object from Realm using `init(value:)`. Because ObjectMapper assign values to model's properties even when serializing. It just assigns same value, it does not modified, but Realm doesn't allow assign any value without transaction.

> Note: Generating a JSON string of a Realm Object using ObjectMappers' `toJSON` function only works within a Realm write transaction. This is caused because ObjectMapper uses the `inout` flag in its mapping functions (`<-`) which are used both for serializing and deserializing. Realm detects the flag and forces the `toJSON` function to be called within a write block even though the objects are not being modified.

See also ObjectMapper + Realm section in ObjectMapper's document.

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#objectmapper--realm

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much.